# How do I properly escape double quotes in strings nested in a JSON object located in a CSV column?

Tags: php, json, csv, escaping, fgetcsv

I have a use case where a customer needs to load JSON-serialized objects via a CSV import.  Some of these objects contain strings which contain double-quotes.  Typically I would simply add a '\' before the nested double-quote in order to escape it, however this seems to conflict with the parsing of the CSV file.  We're using PHP 7.0 and the function "fgetcsv" to read the lines of the file.  Whenever I do this I notice odd behavior after an escaped double-quote is encountered.  Here's a sample row from the CSV:

```
"{""test"": ""\""this\"" is a test""}"
```

And here is how PHP reads this column using fgetcsv:

```
{"test": "\"this\"" is a test""}"
```

I have confirmed any double-quotes after the initial escaped double-quote run into this problem.  Thinking the backslash may be causing issues with escaping I tried using another backslash to escape the backslash:

```
"{""test"": ""\\""this\\"" is a test""}"
```

And here's the result:

```
{"test": "\\"this\\" is a test"}
```

So while this does resolve the issue with any double-quotes beyond the first, I am left with two backslashes instead of one.

Without changing the underlying code, is there a way to escape this data so that fgetcsv will interpret it appropriately?  Like so:

```
{"test": "\"this\" is a test"}
```

Comment: Do you need these CSVs to be read by anything other than `fgetcsv`?

Comment: @NathanHinchey I can't think of any other use case, so we should be fine to limit the scope to fgetcsv.

Comment: Can you clarify what the desired output is? Is it `{"test": "\"this\" is a test"}`? (So that the evaluated value of `"this"` in JSON is `"this" is a test`)

Comment: @NathanHinchey Precisely.  I added this to the question for clarity as well.

Comment: @NathanHinchey That is actually in the output, not a typo

Comment: Specifically I meant in this output: `{"test": "\"this\"" is a test""}"`; is the `"` after the curly brace a typo?

Comment: @NathanHinchey not a typo.  That double-quote exists in the output.

Comment: That is bizarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `\"` to represent a double quote instead of `""`.

E.g., `"{\"test\": \"\\\"this\\\" is a test\"}"`

Whether this works may depend on the version of `fgetcsv` you are using -- I'm not sure.

---

Alternatively, if you're using `fgetcsv` 5.3 or later, you could try changing the `fgetcsv` parameters to change the enclosure character or escape character so that it doesn't conflict with JSON. See the parameters in [the fgetcsv docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

> #### **enclosure**
>
> The optional enclosure parameter sets the field enclosure character (one character only).
>
> #### **escape**
>
> The optional **escape** parameter sets the escape character (one character only).
>
> Note: Usually an **enclosure** character is escaped inside a field by doubling it; however, the **escape** character can be used as an alternative. So for the default parameter values "" and \" have the same meaning. Other than allowing to escape the **enclosure** character the **escape** character has no special meaning; it isn't even meant to escape itself.

*(emphasis in original)*

Comment: I did see the escape character parameter in the fgetcsv docs, however ideally a solution would only require changing the CSV file itself, not the underlying code.  That may not be possible, but if so that is certainly the preferred solution.

Comment: {\"test\": \"\\\"this\\\" is a test\"} was not parsed correctly either.  It was parsed exactly as it was entered:  {\"test\": \"\\\"this\\\" is a test\"}.  I'm using PHP 7.0.

Comment: Did you enclose it in double quotes? If so, that's SUPER weird, and I'd suggest [logging it as a PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/), and biting the bullet and changing your code. Sorry ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes I did.  Very odd indeed.  Thanks for the recommendations.